# Rest Multiple parentId id's

Tags: api, rest, restful-url

I have a rest resource with the uri:

```
/invoices/1/invoiceitems/34
```

Now I have to add a child of invoice items called invoiceitempieces

Should this be done like this:

```
/invoices/1/invoiceitems/34/invoiceitempieces/7
```

That seems more organized than these options

```
/invoiceitems/34/invoiceitempieces/7
/invoiceitempieces/7
```

I prefer the example with all three IDs but is that best/acceptable practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this seems the most appropriate, conceptually ...

```
/invoices/1/invoiceitems/34/invoiceitempieces/7
```

... you will find it rather difficult to implement (based on my own experience).  You'll find that this ...

```
/invoices
/invoices/1
/invoices/1/invoiceitems
/invoiceitems/34
/invoiceitems/34/invoiceitempieces
/invoiceitempieces/7
```

... is just as useful and much easier to implement, even though it might be a bit less elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to use **HATEOAS**. RESTful URI is opaque.

> A REST API must not define fixed resource names or **hierarchies** (an
>   obvious coupling of client and server). Servers must have the freedom
>   to control their own namespace. Instead, allow servers to instruct
>   clients on how to construct appropriate URIs, such as is done in HTML
>   forms and URI templates, by defining those instructions within media
>   types and link relations. [Failure here implies that clients are
>   assuming a resource structure due to out-of band information, such as
>   a domain-specific standard, which is the data-oriented equivalent to
>   RPC's functional coupling].

see this:
http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to have Id and order for invoiceitems and invoiceitempieces id is unique and "order+invoice_id" combined are unique so you can access the invoiceitempieces throw 2 ways

```
/invoices/{invoice_id}/invoiceitems/{invoiceitems_order}/invoiceitempieces/{invoiceitempieces_order}
/invoiceitems/{invoiceitems_id}/invoiceitempieces/{invoiceitempieces_order}
/invoiceitempieces/{invoiceitempieces_id}
```

so you will have flexibility and also provide more information in the URI "the order" if it is required by client.